# animating images using drwable object

Tags: android, animation, imageview, drawable

i am new to andriod and i would appreciate it if someone can help me.
i am trying to animate a sequence of images (pictures). i read a little about it and it seems that a good way to do it , is to use the drawable object. my code looks like this:

i have an animation.xml file with:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/im1" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/im2" android:duration="200" /> </animation-list>
```

i defined an image view in the main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget32"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"> <ImageView
android:id="@+id/picView"
android:layout_width="500px"
android:layout_height="200px"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"> </ImageView> </RelativeLayout>
```

finally, in my activity, i used the drawable object to do the animation. like this:

```
public class animatePic extends Activity
```

{

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picView);
    image.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
    image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);
    AnimationDrawable imAnimate = (AnimationDrawable)image.getBackground();
    imAnimate.start();

}
```

}

my problem is that i get only the first image instead of endless loop of images.
can anyone help with this?? i am doing the developement on android 2.1 platform (does this has anything to do with this? :)).

many thanks

lipi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the FramebyFrame Animation for this.

You can use this link

http://www.twintechs.com/blog/?p=35

Comment: Hi Hardik  Thanks for your answer. Actually this is what I was tring to do and I fail to see the difference between the 2 codes. Do you see any difference? Thanks

Comment: Hi thanks. i tried your suggestion and it works. it seems i needed to use a new task (the timer task) with the run() method for this.

Comment: by the way, i am new to this, how do i vote for your answer ? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the only problem you have here is that you can't start a AnimationDrawable in the onCreate method.
More explanation here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html , at the end of the document...